# No such file or directory PHP Google Calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

```
set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src/google"); 
require_once 'Client.php';
require_once '/Service/CalendarService.php';
```

Results in:

```
Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\GoogleCalendar\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php on line 18
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php' (include_path='google-api-php-client/src/google') in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\GoogleCalendar\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php on line 18
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: PHP can't find the files at where you're telling it to look for them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm in my /home/user/analytics directory (a blank directory) when I download the analytics API through git:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git
```

I get these errors when I try to use Client.php.  I've modified

/home/user/analytics/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php like so; add four lines before the require lines:

```
$dirArray = explode('/', dirname(__FILE__));
$homeDir = $dirArray[2];

$path = '/home/' . $homeDir . '/analytics/google-api-php-client/src/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```